# How to make IE open iframe pdf links in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, cross-browser

I am using an iframe to show pdf files on an html page as follows.

```
<iframe src="testfile.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

The links inside the pdf should open in a new tab or in the same tab.
In case of IE, the links open inside the iframe itself.

How do i make IE open these links in a new tab or the same tab instead of opening inside the iframe?

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding `target="_blank"`?

```
<iframe src="testfile.pdf" target="_blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried it but it still opens link inside the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.lifewire.com/targeting-links-in-frames-3468670 you can use target = "_blank" in iframe will open in new tab.